Unable to Persist Firebase Auth on a Multiplatform App
Setup

Swift app with both iOS and macOS targets with the same bundle id: com.teamName.appName
App group: group.com.teamName.appName
Keychain sharing group: com.teamName.appName
Authentication setup:
try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("group.com.teamName.appName")
This setup is necessary for maintaining sign-in state in app extensions (notifications, share extension)

Issue

iOS: Auth state persists correctly
macOS: Requires re-authentication each time
Error on macOS:
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17995 "An error occurred when accessing the keychain."

Attempted Fix

Changed app group from group.com.teamName.appName to teamId.group.com.teamName.appName
This approach mimics the automatic behavior for keychain groups
Reasoning behind the fix:
a. Keychain groups automatically prepend the team ID in the entitlements file. For example, setting the keychain group as com.teamName.AppName in the target actually sets it as $(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.teamName.AppName in the entitlements
b. The hypothesis was that app groups might need similar treatment for macOS
Implementation:
a.  Modified the app group identifier in the project settings
b.  Updated the useUserAccessGroup call in the authentication setup:
try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("teamId.group.com.teamName.appName")
c.  Adjusted any other references to the app group throughout the codebase

Result

macOS: Compiles, runs, and persists authentication
iOS: Fails to compile on physical device with error:
Application Group identifiers should start with 'group.'
(Note: Compiles fine in simulator)

Question
How can I resolve this issue to have both iOS and macOS apps compile, run, and persist their authentication state? Is there a way to use different app group identifiers for iOS and macOS within the same target, or should I consider separating the targets?

If you have to compile for both OS independently anyway, could you just use compile time directives #if os(iOS) and #if os(macOS) ?  Your bundle id can remain the same, but when building your parameter string you can prepend the teamId and group to the parameter before making the call
